# Calculate DATE with based on column + IF statement

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, date-time

my calculated date/time function is failing on sharepoint 2010 and I'm not sure why.

```
=YEAR( [Tested:] 
       +IF( [Maintenance Recurrence:]="Yearly"
            ,1
            ,0
          )
     )
```

Will work. But

```
=DATE( 
      YEAR( [Tested:]+IF( [Maintenance Recurrence:]="Yearly",1,0)
          )
     )
```

and more specifically the one I want.

```
=DATE(
    YEAR([Tested:]+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Yearly",1,0))
   ,MONTH([Tested:]+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Monthly",1,0)+IF[Maintenance Recurrence:]="Bi-Annually",6,0))
   ,DAY([Tested:]+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Weekly",7,0)+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Daily",1,0)))
```

Won't.
I'd also like to know if there is an easier way to do this. I couldn't find a function to use to map text to #'s

Follow up question:  I've read that trying to fight sharepoint's concept of how it works is a losing battle... So what's the "sharepoint" way/equivalent of iterating a workflow over all items in a list on a schedule. Because the only solutions I found to do this were EXTREMELY convoluted. (creating two lists with 3 workflows to simulate a foreach loop then putting a powershell script on a task schedule to run the workflow on a recurring basis......)

**SOLUTION**

Thanks Danny,

```
=DATE(
YEAR([Tested:])
+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Yearly",1,0)

,MONTH([Tested:])
+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Monthly",1,0)
+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Bi-Annually",6,0)

,DAY([Tested:])
+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Weekly",7,0)
+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Daily",1,0)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE function wants 3 parameters, so YEAR only doesn't work;

Your last Formula is lacking several **(** after the IFs

Best practice is to create your Formula in Notepad or another decent text-editor;
add loads of linebreaks and spaces/tab so you can read the Formula

That way you will immediatly spot your **(** errors

When you copy/paste into a SharePoint Formula, SP will remove all linebreaks and spaces (so keep that copy in Notepad)

Function reference: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

#### RE: comments

You are doing

```
 =YEAR(
       [Datefield] + 1
      )
```

I presume you mean to do:

```
 =YEAR(
       [Datefield]
      ) + 1
```

Since Dates in SharePoint start counting at december 31st 1899, your version (for YEAR) works for every day but the last day of the year.

But this (adding +1 *inside* the function) goes horribly wrong when you use the MONTH and DAY function

MONTH+1 works for every day BUT the last day of the Month

DAY+1 is wrong for every Day...

Comment: Thanks, What do I use instead of YEAR? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-4db82426-8590-4a56-a057-2f19ff38501e says there is only one output

Comment: The DATE function requires Year,Month,Day parameters, a Date without a month or day doesn't make sense

Comment: The YEAR Function wants a valid Date as parameter

Comment: The YEAR function returns the year. Which I put in the YEAR parameter of the date function. Am I missing something? I changed the editing in my original command, should be more clear.

Comment: [Tested:] will always be a valid date.

Comment: see addition in answer

Answer (score 1):

On your last one you've got some parentheses in the wrong place. Especially when you've got 2 possibilities in the Month and Day sections. Try this:

=DATE(YEAR([Tested:]+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Yearly",1,0))
,MONTH([Tested:]+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Monthly",1,IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Bi-Annually",6,0)))
,DAY([Tested:]+IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Weekly",7,IF([Maintenance Recurrence:]="Daily",1,0))))

Comment: Thanks, fixed in my original comment. But still says formula contains a syntax error or is not supported when I try to save.